# Are the two options for marking a post duplicate same?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, flag-dialog, flag-reasons

Is there any difference between which of the following methods you use to mark a question duplicate?

1. I am flagging to report this question as... ▶ A Duplicate
2. I am flagging to report this question as... ▶ Should be closed ▶ Duplicate of...

Comment: There is no difference I believe

Comment: @rene is right (as usual ;)), both the same.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks again. But the duplicate was certainly hard to find  because of such a *great* title.

Comment: That's what we (veteran long time MSE users) are here for. All good! :-)